# How to set require in vscode Lua settings.json

Tags: lua, require, visual-studio-code

When one wants to include extra Lua libraries in VScode
How should the settings.json look like ?

Essentially my Lua looks like this:

```
   package.path = package.path .. ";D:\\InhouseApp\\1.9.0\\lua\\?.lua"
   vf = require "InhouseApp.vision.filters"  --   this should work but doesnt

   -- the full path which i try to refer to: 
   -- "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\InhouseApp\\1.9.0\\lua\\demo\\vision\\filters.lua"
```

Even if i write the full path in the Lua code itself as in the command it isn't working.
So i think i should alter the settings.json, but dont know the syntax to do it.
All I want to get intellisense working, but it doesnt, so i get text completion of other file functions

Comment: If the full path is "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\InhouseApp\\1.9.0\\lua\\demo\\vision\\filters.lua", why do you use "D:\\InhouseApp\\1.9.0\\lua\\?.lua" ? thats a completely different location

Comment: That was an old location, but it doesnt work with that either, the syntax isnt working. I think it should be in settings.json, but i dont know to syntax of that for LUA to provide includes

Comment: the paths are still different...

Comment: the path shouldstart with  "C:\....  the point is that vscode doesnt make use of it.
Its prototype machine A versus Dev machine B where resides on C:\
Another person was working on it on notepad++ on another Dev machine and he has them on another place as well.
I wanted to have the same intelicense functionalitty as he got in notepad++